# How do i transpose a pandas Dataframe in a way, in which I am only gonna need two columns and one column is for the headline

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe which looks something along the lines of this:

> A            B        C
>   1 Data1  Data2  Data3
>   2 Data3  Data1  Nan
>   3 Nan     Data5  Nan

And basically i want to get a Dataframe which looks like that:

> 1
>   A Data1
>   A Data3
>   B Data2
>   B Data1
>   B Data5
>   C Data3

I already found out that I am probably going to need the transpose function. But I don't know how to go on from there. I would be glad if you could help me out with that or if you find another way which solves this problem.

Comment: Just `df.stack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a bit of function chaining:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index().dropna()
```

`df.stack()` aggregates them in one column but adds a multilevel index so we drop with `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` then we sort the index so it orders the text with `sort_index()` then finally we `dropna()`.

Outputs:

```
A    Data1
A    Data3
B    Data2
B    Data1
B    Data5
C    Data3
```

If you take off each chained assignment and run them individually you can see what each intermediate step is doing:
`df.stack()` then `df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`, then `df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()`